# Design patterns for tensorflow models

Tags: tensorflow

I created several simple models, mostly based on some tutorials. From what I've done, I feel that models are quite hard to reuse, and I feel that I need to create some structure with classes to encapsulate the models.

What are the 'standard' ways of structuring tensorflow models? Are there any coding conventions/best practices for this?

Comment: The question isn't too broad. Tensorflow at google and it would be nice if somebody from there share their convention to structure models.

Answer (score 5):

Throughout the Tensorflow examples and tutorials the prominent pattern for structuring model code is, to split the model up into three functions:

- `inference(inputs, ...)` which builds the model
- `loss(logits, ...)` which adds the loss on top of the logits
- `train(loss, ...)` which adds training ops

When creating a model for training, your code would look something like this:

```
inputs = tf.placeholder(...)
logits = mymodel.inference(inputs, ...)
loss = mymodel.loss(logits, ...)
train = mymodel.train(loss, ...)
```

This pattern is used for the CIFAR-10 Tutorial for example ([code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10.py), [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn)).

One thing one might stumble over is the fact that you cannot share (Python) variables between the `inference` and the `loss` function. That is not a big issue though, since Tensorflow provides [Graph collections](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/framework#Graph_collections) for exactly this use case, making for a much cleaner design (since it makes you group your things logically). One major use case for this is regularization:

If you are using the `layers` module (e.g. `tf.layers.conv2d`) you already have what you need, since all regularization penalties will be added ([source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/1a1527ab1fcffd94f692b1301fdbe87903ce7bdb/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py#L258)) to the collection `tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES` by default. For example when you do this:

```
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
    inputs,
    filters=96,
    kernel_size=11,
    strides=4,
    activation=tf.nn.relu,
    kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.01),
    kernel_regularizer=tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(),
    name='conv1')
```

Your loss could look like this then:

```
def loss(logits, labels):
    softmax_loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(
        onehot_labels=labels,
        logits=logits)

    regularization_loss = tf.add_n(tf.get_collection(
        tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)))

    return tf.add(softmax_loss, regularization_loss)
```

If you are not using the layers module, you would have to populate the collection manually (just like in the linked source snippet). Basically you want to add the penalties to the collection using [`tf.add_to_collection`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/add_to_collection):

```
tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES, reg_penalty)
```

With this you can calculate the loss including the regularization penalties just like above.

Comment: It's a nice pattern, but there's a problem here. It won't work if we have a regularization term as a part of the loss.

Comment: There is a nice way of doing this using Graph Collections, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume this image is helpful and all model types presented in here may be also coded in TenfsorFlow.

[image]

Comment: I think that design patterns in the topic refers to the organizing source code into reusable pieces. Rather now designing structure of neural networks